# Showing that $f(x)=2xe^{x}+1$ is injective for $x \geq -1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, inverse-function

How do you show that $f(x)=2xe^{x}+1$ is injective for $x \geq -1$?

If you choose two points $a,b \in D_f$, and say $f(a)=f(b)$ you'll get $ae^a=be^b$, but isn't this like solving the equation $x=e^x$? The idea was to end up with $a=b$.

Comment: "but isn't this like solving the equation x=ex"  don't need to solve it.  Just need to know a solution exists.

Comment: Also.  If $a < b$ then $e^a < e^b$ and if $a \ge 0$ then $ae^a < be^b$ (will have to do something for $x < 0$.)

Comment: Agreed to that; "just need to show a solution exist" - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

$\frac d {dx} (xe^{x})=xe^{x}+e^{x}=(1+x)e^{x} >0$ for $x >-1$. So $xe^{x}$ is strictly increasing on $(-1,\infty)$. Can you finish?

Comment: Yes... that was easy! I got so stuck in the method I tried in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Showing that the function is strictly increasing is enough to show that it's injective. (In general, strictly monotonic functions are injective)

Simply take the derivative and check that it's strictly greater than 0.